# Complex Polar Form Sum

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z = a + bi \in \mathbb{C}$. So the polar form of $z$ is:

$$\left| z \right| \left[ \cos \left( \arg \left( z \right) \right) + i \sin \left( \arg \left( z \right) \right) \right] = \rho e^{\theta i}; ~ \rho = \left| z \right|, ~ \theta = \arg \left( z \right)$$

This form is interesting because when we multiply two complex polar form numbers, the new number is also in polar form. But, if we want to sum two complex numbers in polar form, how can the result be a polar form too:

$$z_1 + z_2 = \rho _1 e^{\theta _1 i} + \rho _2 e^{\theta _2 i} = \rho _3 e^{\theta _3 i}$$

What is $\rho _3$ and $\theta _3$?

Comment: **Hint:** convert from polar to binomial, add up, then convert to polar. Or if you want your math to be purely polar, draw the vectors as in a parallelogram rule diagram, then use the law of cosines.

Comment: The polar form is good for product, the cartesian form for the sum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding two polar forms ($\rho_1 \angle \theta_1 + \rho_2 \angle \theta_2$) with unequal angles is not as simple as multiplying two polar forms; it takes a little more creativity.

- If the *angles* are equal ($\theta_1 = \theta_2$), then obviously $\rho_1 \angle \theta_1 + \rho_2 \angle \theta_1 = (\rho_1 + \rho_2) \angle \theta_1$.
- If the *moduli* are equal (i.e. $\rho_1 = \rho_2$), then we can use the sum-to-product formulas to add up polar forms with unequal angles.

$$z_1 + z_2 = \rho(\cos \theta_1 + i \sin \theta_1) + \rho (\cos \theta_2 + i \sin \theta_2) \\ = \rho ((\cos \theta_1 + \cos \theta_2) + i (\sin \theta_1 + \sin \theta_2)) \\ 2 \rho \bigg(\cos \bigg ( \dfrac {\theta_1 + \theta_2}{2} \bigg )\cos \bigg ( \dfrac {\theta_1 - \theta_2}{2} \bigg )+ i \bigg(\sin \bigg ( \dfrac {\theta_1 + \theta_2}{2} \bigg )\cos \bigg ( \dfrac {\theta_1 - \theta_2}{2} \bigg )\bigg)$$

Factoring, we get

$$2 \rho \cos \bigg ( \dfrac {\theta_1 - \theta_2}{2} \bigg) \bigg(\cos \bigg ( \dfrac {\theta_1 + \theta_2}{2} \bigg )+ i \sin \bigg ( \dfrac {\theta_1 + \theta_2}{2} \bigg )\bigg )$$

The exponential form is $$2 \rho \cos \bigg ( \dfrac {\theta_1 - \theta_2}{2} \bigg) \cdot e^{i(\theta_1 + \theta_2)}$$ while the polar form is $$2 \rho \cos \bigg ( \dfrac {\theta_1 - \theta_2}{2} \bigg) \angle \dfrac {(\theta_1 + \theta_2)}{2}$$  Thus, $\rho_3 = 2 \rho \cos \bigg ( \dfrac {\theta_1 - \theta_2}{2} \bigg)$ and $\theta_3 = \dfrac {(\theta_1 + \theta_2)}{2}$.

- If *neither* the moduli nor the arguments of $z_1$ and $z_2$ are  equal, then we can find $\rho_3$ and $\theta_3$ as follows...

**Using the cartesian form**

Let $z_1 = \alpha_1 + i \beta_1$ and $z_2 = \alpha_2+ i \beta_2$. Then $$\rho_3 = |z_1 + z_2| = \sqrt {(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2)^2 + (\beta_1 + \beta_2)^2}$$ and $$\theta_3 = \arg (z_1 + z_2) = \text {atan2} (\beta_1 + \beta_2, \alpha_1 + \alpha_2)$$ with the following conditions:

$$\theta_3 = \begin{cases}
\arctan \dfrac {\beta_1 + \beta_2}{\alpha_1 + \alpha_2}, & \text{if $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 \gt 0$} \\
\arctan \dfrac {\beta_1 + \beta_2}{\alpha_1 + \alpha_2} + \pi, & \text{if $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 \lt 0$ and $\beta_1 + \beta_2 \geq 0$} \\
\arctan \dfrac {\beta_1 + \beta_2}{\alpha_1 + \alpha_2} - \pi, & \text{if $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 \lt 0$ and $\beta_1 + \beta_2 \lt 0$} \\
+\dfrac {\pi}{2},& \text{if $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 = 0$ and $\beta_1 + \beta_2 \gt 0$} \\
-\dfrac {\pi}{2},& \text{if $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 = 0$ and $\beta_1 + \beta_2 \lt 0$}
\end{cases}$$

**Using the polar form**

Let $z_1 = r_1 (\cos \alpha_1 + i \sin \beta_1)$ and $z_2 = r_2 (\cos \alpha_2+ i \sin \beta_2)$. Then $$\rho_3 = |z_1 + z_2| = \sqrt {(r_1 \cos \alpha_1 + r_2 \cos \alpha_2)^2 + (r_1 \sin \beta_1 + r_2 \sin \beta_2)^2}$$ and $$\theta_3 = \arg (z_1 + z_2) = \text {atan2} (\sin \beta_1 + \sin \beta_2, \cos \alpha_1 + \cos \alpha_2)$$ with the following conditions:

$$\theta_3 = \begin{cases}
\arctan \dfrac {\sin \beta_1 + \sin \beta_2}{\cos \alpha_1 + \cos \alpha_2}, & \text{if $\cos \alpha_1 + \cos \alpha_2 \gt 0$} \\
\arctan \dfrac {\sin \beta_1 + \sin \beta_2}{\cos \alpha_1 + \cos \alpha_2} + \pi, & \text{if $\cos \alpha_1 + \cos \alpha_2 \lt 0$ and $\sin \beta_1 + \sin \beta_2 \geq 0$} \\
\arctan \dfrac {\sin \beta_1 + \sin \beta_2}{\cos \alpha_1 + \cos \alpha_2} - \pi, & \text{if $\cos \alpha_1 + \cos \alpha_2 \lt 0$ and $\sin \beta_1 + \sin \beta_2 \lt 0$} \\
+\dfrac {\pi}{2},& \text{if $\cos \alpha_1 + \cos \alpha_2 = 0$ and $\sin \beta_1 + \sin \beta_2 \gt 0$} \\
-\dfrac {\pi}{2},& \text{if $\cos \alpha_1 + \cos \alpha_2 = 0$ and $\sin \beta_1 + \sin \beta_2 \lt 0$}
\end{cases}$$

In either form, if $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 = \beta_1 + \beta_2 = 0$ , or $\cos \alpha_1 + \cos \alpha_2 = \sin \beta_1 + \sin \beta_2 = 0$, $\rho_3$ and $\theta_3$ will be *undefined*.

Comment: In general, the argument of a complex number $a+bi$ can't be obtained just by taking $\arctan\frac ba$

Comment: @jjagmath I've updated my post...I replaced the arctangent function with the two-argument arctangent function.